# Copy files from tfs versioncontrol to directory with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-power-tools

Does somebody know if it is possible to Copy files from TFS (2013 Update 2) source control to a specific folder on your computer?

Let's say I have the server path `$/BuildTemplate2013/BuildProcessSource` and I want all the files of that directory to be copied/downloaded to `C:\destinationDir` with PowerShell. Is that possible? I have the TFS 2013 Update 2 Power tools installed but I can't find any command for that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've created a PowerShell script that connects to the TFS server with the TFS assemblies. I then loop through the files on the server (in a specific path) and download it recursively.

```
# The deploy directory for all the msi, zip etc.
$AutoDeployDir = "Your TFS Directory Server Path"
$deployDirectory = $($Env:TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION + "\Deploy\" + $Env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)

# Add TFS 2013 dlls so we can download some files
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
$tfsCollectionUrl = 'http://YourServer:8080/tfs/YourCollection' 
$tfsCollection = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection -ArgumentList $tfsCollectionUrl
$tfsVersionControl = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])

# Register PowerShell commands
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell

# Get all directories and files in the AutoDeploy directory
$items = Get-TfsChildItem $AutoDeployDir -Recurse

# Download each item to a specific destination
foreach ($item in $items) {
    # Serverpath of the item
    Write-Host "TFS item to download:" $($item.ServerItem) -ForegroundColor Blue

    $destinationPath = $item.ServerItem.Replace($AutoDeployDir, $deployDirectory)
    Write-Host "Download to" $([IO.Path]::GetFullPath($destinationPath)) -ForegroundColor Blue

    if ($item.ItemType -eq "Folder") {
        New-Item $([IO.Path]::GetFullPath($destinationPath)) -ItemType Directory -Force
    }
    else {
        # Download the file (not folder) to destination directory
        $tfsVersionControl.DownloadFile($item.ServerItem, $([IO.Path]::GetFullPath($destinationPath)))
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add `-Server $tfsCollection` after `$items = Get-TfsChildItem $AutoDeployDir -Recurse` to get this running, then it worked like a champ.

Comment: Maybe because we only have one Collection in this company is the reason why I didn't needed that? I've made this for TFS2013

Comment: Ah I am on 2010 - regardless, thanks for the script, it saved me a lot of time. I just wanted to mention that in case anyone else had a similar problem.

Comment: I am trying to use your script and I am cloning the repository from https://example.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/, What should I put in the AutoDeployDir. my clone url is https://example.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/playground/_git/objfolder. I've tried the full path, used $/playground and other combinations till the final folder, but items list is always empty

Comment: @RalphJansen - Awesome. I see right now it's using credentials from appdata/cache for TFS. Do you have any idea by using which libraries we can pass specific credentials in script itself, instead of using credentials from local cache?

Answer (score 3):

The PowerShell option is not selected by default in your when you install TFS Power Tools.

Select the option to install TFS powershell tools.

[image]

You can then use the Update-TfsWorkspace commandlet to get latest files. Please make sure you have a workspace already created for the directory where you need to latest files to get to. Then execute the following

```
cd <Your Directory Path>

Update-TfsWorkspace
```

While executing the command let, please make sure that that the workspace is created for the user that going to execute the powershell.

Just execute it on a

Comment: But how can I specify a specific directory on my drive like `C:\destinationDir`? I'm calling this script from my build process template and need to change some files.

Comment: One of the ways to do it is to execute your PowerShell commandlets from the directory where you you want copy it from. You would need to have a workspace mapping set up already for that folder to be able to do it.

Comment: That command only *lists* the server's contents. It is the equivalent of `tf dir`.  It doesn't actually retrieve files onto the local filesystem.

Comment: You are right. Apologies!! 

You need to run the commandlet "Update-TfsWorkspace". 

Just execute it without any parameters on a directory that already has a workspace set up. 

I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the information but I created the script slightly different because I didn't want to use a workspace.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is `tf.exe get` and that comes with the TFS client tools i.e. Visual Studio or the Team Explorer stand-alone tool.  You will need to have a workspace and work folder mapping configured in order to use `tf.exe get`.

If you prefer to use the TF Power Tools then use the `Update-TfsWorkspace` command to get files.  I believe you will still need a workspace defined with a workfold mapping.

```
Update-TfsWorkspace -Item $/TeamProject/Path/Path2/Item -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the rest api

```
    $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

    $fileName = "<FILENAME>"
    $tfsMappingPath = "$/<TFS_MAPPING>/$fileName"
    $url = "<TFS_URL>/_apis/tfvc/items?path=$tfsMappingPath"

    $WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true

    $WebClient.DownloadFile($url,"$pwd/$fileName")
```