# How to set up CI/CD on TFS--importing dependencies?

Tags: git, dll, tfs, continuous-integration, devops

I'm setting up CI on my project, and I'm having trouble getting some DLLs installed. The set up is as follows: repo sits on a TFSGIT 2015 server. I set up a build server (agent) on a VM. When the code gets checked in, the build server builds, runs the tests, etc. The builds are failing because some internal packages/DLLs (that are sitting on a different TFS 2010 server) cannot be found.

My question is: what's the best way to solve this? I guess a crude approach is to simply add the DLLs to the repo, but I was wondering if there is a pre-build step where I can import the DLLs from the TFS 2010 server. Would a simple power shell script do it?

I'm unfamiliar with the microsoft stack so any guidance/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this, you could:

1. Create a NUGET package of the functionality you are using and host this internally. The bonus here is that you are doing things in an appropriate build manner from a CICD perspective and maintaining appropriate versioning so that you can, in the future, ensure that you can rebuild an exact instance of a version. When you do a NUGET RESTORE step, you can simply add the arguments: -source

   - In VSTS/TFS2017 you can add your own NUGET feed.
   - You can create one simply with code. [Hanselman: Creating your own Nuget Feed](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx)
   - You can use a 3rd party host.
2. (Assuming your remote TFS isn't storing versioned builds of these) Use a build step to copy those files out of the remote TFS server into a versioning system, applying the version details as meta-data. Again, the concern here is being able to fully ensure that you can roll-back effectively at a given time.
3. Use Powershell to grab a specific build-version artifact from your TFS server, here is an example script to grab the latest build. If your DLL projects utilize builds, you can use this - this should be trivial to modify to grab a specific build. I would do this via some build variables, personally. The biggest thing to note here is the "DropLocation", that will be the file drop for the Artifact. [Mike Poulson: Get last known good build via Powershell](http://www.mikepoulson.com/2013/04/tfs-2012-how-to-get-last-known-good.html)
4. Directly use a Powershell script to copy the data from the other TFS in a build script. At the minimum, saving this in your artifact will suffice to roll-back at a minimum, but I like to ensure that I can build backwards as well especially with larger projects. Just in case something drastic happens with your artifact storage. This answer can help you: [Copy files from bfs version control to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739499/copy-files-from-tfs-versioncontrol-to-directory-with-powershell) 
   There are also powershell tools to help with this.

There are probably countless ways to resolve this, but my suggestion would be to take a step back and architect it the right way; in this instance, you want to make sure that if a remote build is occurring and creating depend artifacts, that you are managing them appropriately and capturing them in relation to a specific build. That's why I still suggest utilizing your own NUGET feeds.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. Couldn't have asked for a better answer! For our immediate needs (I'm attempting to to give a 'proof of concept' of all of this to get mgmt on board), #2 will work. Presumably this is part of a pre-build step in the build definition? Assuming everything goes well #1 is definitely the way to go since the versioning will give our team precise data if we need to go back to a particular build. Thanks again.