# TFS 2017 Build definition: how to get sources from another TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I have two different TFS instances. Both use TFVC as a source control.

I want to set up a build definition on TFS1, so that it gets sources from TFS2. Is it possible to do it?

There is no option "Remote TFVC", only "Remove Git".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it isn't supported in either TFS On-Prem, or VSTS. Depending on your needs, circumstances and limitations, you might consider one of the following options (all are more or less trade-offs):

- **Migrate sources from TFS2 to TFS1 (the one to run builds)**

  This seems to be the correct thing to do, but it is a time-consuming and error-prone process
- **Fake the Get Sources action and do the real get/checkout in the first build step**

  You can configure the Get Sources step to address any Git repo in the same team project, and turn the *Don't sync sources* flag ON. Then, in the first real build step, run command-line Get (something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command?view=vsts))

Answer (score 0):

You may use custom build step (cmd or bat file) and download files from remote server. Examples:

1. [Copy files from tfs versioncontrol to directory with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739499/copy-files-from-tfs-versioncontrol-to-directory-with-powershell)
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9559f7a5-405a-456c-a66b-8123d52ed23a/how-to-copy-a-folder-from-tfs-source-control-to-shared-location-with-powershell-script?forum=tfsgeneral

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the extension to get them from an external vsts/tfs.
Go to the marketplace and search for them (see image).

You will have to configure a endpoint to your external vsts/tfs, but it is quit easy to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install this extension: [TFS artifacts for Release Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-externaltfs).

Then add a `Download Artifacts-External TFVC` task from Utility.

[image]

Comment: @Vladimir Melekh Have you solved the issue? any update?